# Div AutoResize (as if it were empty)

Tags: html, css, autosize

[image]

I have a row of divs.  All the divs on the left resize to fit their content.  I want the div on the left to resize to fit its content as well, but I want it to be subservient to the divs on the right.  So if the divs on the right get really big the div on the left will cut off its content ( however long it is) and scrunch down to a size that accommodated the divs on the right.

This works find if the left div is empty but if it has content in it then it wont resize.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: try with `min-width` for the autoresize div's

Comment: So do all 3 divs combined have a max width they are allowed to be? which is why when the right ones get larger they start to take up the space the left one used to have?

Comment: yes all three add up to a max width.  the two right auto size to fit thier contents the one left auto sizes to the space left over while ignoring its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6WuVz/

HTML with reordered elements:

```
<div class="r">Right 1</div>
<div class="r">Right 2</div>
<div class="l">Left</div>
```

CSS:

```
.r {
    float: right;
}

.l {
    overflow: hidden; /* turn into a "Block Formatting Context" */
}
```

Read more about how BFCs take the remaining space left by floats:

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/

BFC for old IEs:

```
display: block; overflow:hidden; zoom:1; position:relative;
```

Comment: This appears to work, but not in IE6.  Any ideas on how to get this working in older version of IE?

Comment: Thanks, unfrotunatly i'm still not able to get it working... You can see my test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/6WuVz/19/

Comment: Do you really have to support IE6? :) I updated some things here (added a wrapper to the left panel), but I couldn't try it on IE6: http://jsfiddle.net/6WuVz/23/ The wrapper is necessary because ie6 doesn't like too wide elements inside BFCs, that's why the 100% width inner wrapper (which destroys `text-overflow:ellipsis`). Good luck with IE! :)

Comment: lol, In a few years probably no but a signifigant portion of the sites user base is in a rural area and i'm sure will have outdated copies of IE.  I'll just change the design.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and/or height on page load after the other div sizes are already calculated.  Using jquery:

```
$( function() {
   $("#leftdiv").width($("#rightdiv").width()) 
   $("#leftdiv").height($("#rightdiv").height());
});
```